# Kubernetes pods not establishing connection within the same node with error code `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes, axios

I have the following microservice based node.js program: `posts` is responsible for creating a post and sending the corresponding event to the `event bus` via an axios `POST` request. The `event bus` also establishes connection to `posts` via an axios `GET` request upon startup.
The `GET` request from `event bus` to `posts` is successful, but the `POST` request from `posts` to `event bus` fails with the error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND event-bus-srv`. Both `posts` and `event bus` are running in pods managed by kubernetes within the same node. Only `posts` is available to the user vis the URL `http://localhost:31218/`. When I use postman to post to the endpoint `http://localhost:31218/posts`, I receive code 201 successfully, but the event is never forwarded to `event bus`.
My question is this: what is causing `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND event-bus-srv` and how do I fix it?

Relavent code:

1. posts index.js
2. event bus index.js
3. EVENT BUS KUBERNETES DEPLOYMENT FILE
4. POSTS KUBERNETES DEPLOYMENT FILE
5. POSTS KUBERNETES NODEPORT FILE

```
_____________________________________POSTS___________________________________________
const express = require('express');
const { randomBytes } = require('crypto');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const posts = {};


app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
  res.send(posts);
});

app.post('/posts', async(req, res) => {
  const id = randomBytes(4).toString('hex');
  const { title } = req.body;
  posts[id] = {
    id, title
  };

  await axios.post('http://event-bus-srv:4005/events', {
      type: 'PostCreated',
      data: {
        id, title
      }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("сбой такой: " + err.message);
  });

  res.status(201).send(posts[id]);
});

app.post('/events', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200);
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Listening to port ' + 4000);
});

_____________________________________EVENT BUS___________________________________________
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const events = [];

app.get('/events', (req, res) => {
    res.send(events);
});

app.post('/events', (req, res) => {
    const event = req.body;

    events.push(event);

    axios.post('http://posts-clusterip-svr:4000/events', event).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });

    res.send({status: 'OK'});
});

app.listen(4005, async() => {
    console.log("listening to " + 4005);
    const res = await axios.get('http://posts-clusterip-svr:4000/posts').catch((err) => {
      console.log("сбой такой: " + err.message);
    });
});

___________EVENT BUS KUBERNETES DEPLOYMENT/SERVICE FILE_________________________________

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: event-bus-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: event-bus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: event-bus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: event-bus
          image: wliamwhite/event-bus:latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: event-bus-svr
spec:
  selector:
    app: event-bus
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: event-bus
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4005
      targetPort: 4005

___________POSTS KUBERNETES DEPLOYMENT/SERVICE FILE_____________________________________
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: posts-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: wliamwhite/posts:latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-clusterip-svr
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - name: posts
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000

___________POSTS KUBERNETES NODEPORT FILE_________________________________________
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-svr
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - name: posts
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

Comment: You're trying to POST to `event-bus-srv`, but your Service is named `event-bus-svr` (the last two letters are swapped).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the event-bus-srv and event-bus-svr name confusion. The error message you are having typically indicates that the DNS resolution failed from the hostname.

Things to consider for this concern:

1. Just like what @DavidMaze mentioned you need to double check the hostname and make sure it is properly spelled.
2. Double check also the configuration files or code where the hostname is used.
3. Make sure that DNS servers are correctly configured. You can do a ping or nslookup command for testing.
4. Make sure hostname is properly configured in DNS record and point to the right IP address
5. Check firewall Rules that might be blocking the connection from hostname and ensure necessary ports are open.